# Uncaught ReferenceError: getWidget is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to call a function in **index.php** but I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: getWidget is not defined`. When I call the function in the **widget.php** it works. How can I get the function **getWidget();** to work in **index.php**?

I also get this warning in **index.php**

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/widget.php".
```

and this error in **widget.php**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

---

Here is index.php and widget.php

**index.php**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='widget.php'></script>

<a href="#" onclick="getWidget();">Launch Widget</a>
```

**widget.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type='text/javascript' src='/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js'></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var http = getHTTPObject();

    function doauth() {
        setTimeout("doauth();", 15000);
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
        iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
        iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        iframe.src = "api.php";
        http.open("GET", "api.php");
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
        http.send(null);
    }

    function handleHttpResponse() {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
      if (http.responseText != '') {
        rslt = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById('gw_content').innerHTML = rslt;
        first_time = '';
            }
            // http.onreadystatechange = function(){};
      // http.abort();
        }
    }

    function getHTTPObject() {
        var xmlhttp;
        /*@cc_on
        @if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (E) {
                    xmlhttp = false;
                }
            }
        @else
        xmlhttp = false;
        @end @*/
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getWidget() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }   
</script>

<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <b style="color: #000;">Modal</b>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Modal</h4>
            <p>Instructions...</p><br />
                <div id="gw_content">
                    <body onload="doauth();" />
                    <img src="wheel-throb.gif">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" onclick="getWidget();">Open</button>
```

Comment: Why are you providing a `.php` extension to a `script src` attribute?

Comment: You can not stick body tags in random locations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few areas of concerns, such as linking a `.php` extension into a `script src` attribute, that's causing one of your error message in `index.php` to appear.

However, to resolve the issue of `getWidget` not being defined, I would remove the `<script>` block from `widget.php` into a separate `.js` file (ie, `yourfile.js`) and access it in your `index.php` file like so,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='yourfile.js'></script>
<a href="#" onclick="getWidget();">Launch Widget</a>
```

Also, within `widget.php` are there any PHP code inside that file? If not, then you should rename it to a `.html` or `.htm` extension for clarity.

Comment: How would I go about getting `#myModal` and the html code that is inside widget.php

Comment: If you associate the `.js` file inside of your `index.php` or rather, `index.html` / `index.htm` if deemed necessary, you can access the function that way.